# adb shell su: permission denied

Tags: adb, htc, superuser, pattern-lock

I was trying to unlock my android phone by adb installed. I tried to followed these steps:

```
adb devices adb shell cd data/system su rm *.key
```

But when I typed and enter `su`, it's showing permission denied. My phone is also rooted, but I don't know why after entering `su` it's showing permission denied.

Can you please tell what extra steps I have to do so that I don't get permission denied?

Answer (score 7):

Most superuser apps don't allow adb su access by default. Depending on the app you used the option may vary in location, but basically you need to go to settings in the superuser app and change it from "apps only" to "apps and adb." This should allow you to use su in an adb shell.

Comment: I have used this Superuser app ---> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.noshufou.android.su But don't know, how to change "apps only" to "apps and adb". I did search in settings but didn't found such a thing. Can you please tell me how to do that ?PLease check it and tell me..

Comment: Oh wow, that is a very old superuser app. What device do you have? Is there a particular reason you used this superuser app versus one of the newer ones like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.superuser) or [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu)? It may be an issue with that particular superuser app.